Retrieve log from API calls from external system to SFMC
Is there a way to have log on the API calls made to insert data in SFMC's data extension from external system ?
We do have a daily call which integrate data to a data extension and I would like to know if we can have access to event log in SFMC to monitor if all the calls are made properly.
If so, what query should I use to have these logs and what kind of information do I need to query properly these logs ?

The closest you get to this logging is Audit Trail. However, this does not hold any information about your API requests towards endpoints in SFMC.
When it comes to API/integration monitoring, is also not dealing with this on the receiving end, but more on the sending end. Your external system should be accountable for maintaining the integration, error handling, retries, etc. Errored requests which are a result of failed authentication, or incorrect endpoint URL might not even reach SFMC.
Your best way of monitoring whether you are successful in receiving data is to have each request populating a timestamp field in the data extension. You could then query this data extension on e.g. hourly basis, to validate if you have received any updates. Querying records updated since last check, into an additional data extension, would allow you to use Verification Activity to alert someone, if no records have been updated (record count in this addional DE is 0)
